# Laravel where to execute the cmd command to generate a controller template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have download Laravel using composer and then I used the cmd to generate a project, the project was generated on the `c:/users/user/laravel` directly, I moved it to `c:/xampp/hdocs` and it is working. I am able to create a new controller, a new view, or a new Route

#### My problem

I want to generate a template for a controller. I read that I have to execute this command `$ php artisan Usercontroller:make users`

#### My question

where to execute it?

in my hdoc folder, or controller folder or what?

I am using windows 7 with laravel 4.2

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just navigate to your project's root folder, for example `c:/xampp/hdocs/myProject` and then from the command prompt run the command, for example:

```
php artisan controller:make UserController
```

This will create a resourceful controller named `UserController` in `myProject/app/controllers` folder so if your project's folder is `myProject` then the path will be:

```
c:/xampp/hdocs/myProject/app/controllers/UserController.php
```

You have use `php artisan Usercontroller:make users` but it should be:

> php artisan controller:make ControllerName

Comment: Have you changed the command please? what was wrong in my command?

Comment: `php artisan controller:make UserController` will create the `UserController.php`, you have used `php artisan Usercontroller` but there is no artisan command as `Usercontroller`.

Comment: Yes that works, Many thanks. However, it seems that I am unable to accept your answer nor upvote it because I don't have enough points.

Comment: You can only accept my answer after 15 minutes of asking, it seems it has been passed only 10 minutes and you can only accept one answer. Only `upvotes` requires minimum `15` points/reps but not for accepting an answer.

Comment: yes I still have one minute to accept your answer, please is there a command that I can use to generate controller and the corresponding views? for example: view for `create`, view for `edit`?

Comment: There is no built in way generate the view but you can use a package for that and it's [JeffreyWay's generator](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators).

Comment: I accepted the answer, now it has a green sign on it. So sorry for keep asking but please is Laravel a good php framework? I am not that good in php and I choose it yesterday

Comment: It's one of the bests so far, you are on the right track (IMO) :-)

Comment: I truly thank you for being gentleman. Your help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to execute the `artisan` commands in the root directory of your Laravel project. i.e. navigate to `C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel` in your case and run the command that you wanted. Example:

php artisan UserController:make users

Note: Also the name of the controller is `UserController` not `Usercontroller`. I have noticed that the name of the folder inside your xampp directory is `hdocs` but I think it should be `htdocs` by default. If `hdocs` is indeed the name of the folder then substitute `htdocs` for `hdocs`.